# ggplotly: show tooltips at hoovering over any position of the lines

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

Given:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(iris, aes(label=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))
ggplotly(p)
a <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3,2),Type=rep(1:3,2), Sepal.Length=rep(5:7,2), Sepal.Width=rep(c(0,5),rep(3,2)))
a
```

I can add reference lines with,
eg: #as suggested in [ggplotly: conflict of labels for tooltip with data of added layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77397224/ggplotly-conflict-of-labels-for-tooltip-with-data-of-added-layer)

```
p2 <- geom_line(data = a, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Type,  group=ID,label=NA))
p + p2
ggplotly(p+p2)
```

Is there a way I could see the tooltips of the vertical lines when I hoover over any
place on the lines (currently the tooltips are just shown at the extremes)?
(I do not see the suggestion in [How to add tooltips to geom_abline & geom_hline using ggplotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948094/how-to-add-tooltips-to-geom-abline-geom-hline-using-ggplotly) as a good solution).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `layout(hovermode = 'x')` is what you are searching for:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

a <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3,2),Type=rep(1:3,2), Sepal.Length=rep(5:7,2), Sepal.Width=rep(c(0,5),rep(3,2)))

p = ggplot(iris, aes(label=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))

p2 <- geom_line(data = a, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Type,  group=ID,label=NA))
p + p2
ggplotly(p+p2) |> layout(hovermode = 'x') |> style(p, hoverinfo = "none", traces = c(1L))
```

Please see the related documentation [here](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-hovermode).

Comment: This setting affects lines and points altogether. While the behavior for the lines is correct, the behavior for the points is very inconvenient. The problem is that with the (by default) "closest" option, the tooltips seem to be linked to points, even in the case of the lines. As the lines are defined by 2 points, the tooltip is displayed when hovering over those 2 points.

Comment: @user2955884, I'm aware of the behaviour. However, I guess this is the best you'll get with the current options.

Comment: @user2955884 the only thing we could do is not displaying the hoverinfo for the scatter trace at all using `hoverinfo = "none"` or `hoverinfo = "skip"`. However, I don't know if this is desired. Please see my edit.